SPSS: Create a variable which reports the variable name of the MAX function
I need to create a variable in SPSS, that looks at a series of variables for the maximum value for each case, but reports the variable name (rather than the actual figure).
I know I can use the MAX function to report the actual figure (SEE THE CODE BOX)
But I'd like the maximum_var variable to report which variable the highest figure is from e.g. is it from var_1, var_2 or var_3
COMPUTE maximum_var=MAX(var_1,var_2,var_3).
EXECUTE.

Sample dataset

var_1   var_2    var_3
1.00    2.00    3.00
1.00    1.00    1.00
1.00    3.00    5.00
2.00    2.00    6.00
8.00    2.00    1.00
5.00    7.00    3.00
23.00   4.00    15.00

How do I get the above to report the variable name?

After you've got the maximum value you can loop throught the variables and keep the name of the variable that holds that value. Here is one way to do it, assuming variable names are built as in the example and are consecutive in the dataset:
* recreating example to test code on.
data list list/var_1 var_2 var_3 (3f6).
begin data
    1    2    3
    1    1    1
    1    3    5
    2    2    6
    8    2    1
    5    7    3
    23   4    15
end data.

* now we can see how the code works.
COMPUTE maximum_value=MAX(var_1,var_2,var_3).
string maximum_var (a10).
do repeat vr=var_1 to var_3/varnum=1 to 3.
   if vr=maximum_value maximum_var=concat("var_",string(varnum,f1)).
end repeat.
EXECUTE.

Note that if more than one variable holds the maximum value (like in the second row in the example), only the last one in the file will be noted as the maximum variable (so - var_3 in the example).

Thankyou.
I've run the syntax you suggested and unfortunately it doesn't work.
I've added a sample of how the dataset appears in the original question

Your'e right - I had a typo in the code - corrected now. Also added code to recreate the exampe and test the code.
